# Use GBM to find the optimum configuration of variables given certain conditions

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization, cart, boosting

I have a data set containing historical data of a SAG Ball Mill There are two types of variables: Mineral Characteristics, and Mill Paremeters. Mineral Characteristics are given and can not be manipulated, on the other hand, Mill Parameters can be manipulated by operators.

I have used GBM to fit a model that is accurate enough to be used. The question is, can i use the GBM model to get the optimal parameters on the mill given the mineral characteristics?

Edit:
The idea of optimizing the mill parameters is to produce the highest possible throughput given the mineral conditions

The model im using in R is as follows:

```
boost<-gbm(`Throughput.SAG.4`~ 
         SPI + Bwi + X..gruesos.Alimentación.SAG + X..Intermedios.Alimentación.SAG + X..Finos.Alimentación.SAG # Mineral Characteristics 
       +Feeder.Speed + SAG.rpm + Water.Flow, # Mill parameters
              data=data.train,
              cv.folds = 5,
              distribution="gaussian",
              n.trees = 1000,
              shrinkage = 0.5,
              interaction.depth =3,
              n.minobsinnode=10,
```

)

The idea is to use the GBM model to find the best possible combination of Feeder Speed, SAG RPM and Water Flow given the mineral characteristics to produce the highest througput

Comment: Optimal parameters in what sense? Can you add details, such as what is your model/data, as well as what is the goal in manipulating the mill parameters?

Comment: done! added the code in R as well

Comment: The description of the data does not even mention "throughput", yet presumably the data has something to do with throughput, or else I don't understand how the model could be used to optimize that. I was looking more for something like (just an example, if this was linear regression) "I am using least squares to fit a linear regression $y = \beta_1\,x_1 + \beta_2\,x_2 + \epsilon$ where $y$ is throughput, $x_1$ is a mineral characteristic, $x_2$ is a mill parameter. Can I use this model to find the optimal $x_2$ to maximize $y$"

Comment: Can you = yes.  How can you (in code) = details some folks won't like.  How can you (in statistical best practices) = the right way to get the question asked here, and impo, a great question to ask.  You might get some good miles by reviewing "how to ask a question best practices" here.